# typeScript init dynamic class call by name (2345)

Tags: javascript, typescript

### How can I call a class without resorting to conditional statements?

problem: (parameter) item: inputs
Argument of type 'inputs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISelect & IText'.
  Type 'ISelect' is not assignable to type 'ISelect & IText'.
    Property 'placeholder' is missing in type 'ISelect' but required in type 'IText'.(2345)
input.ts(12, 5): 'placeholder' is declared here.

```
interface IInput {
    id: number
    title: string
}
interface ISelect extends IInput { 
    type: "inputSelect",
    value: string
    selects: string[]
}
interface IText extends IInput{
    type: "inputText",
    placeholder: string
    value: string
}
type inputs = ISelect | IText

class InputSelect implements ISelect {
    public id: number
    public title: string
    public value: string
    public selects: string[]
    public type: ISelect['type'] = "inputSelect"

    constructor(
        inputs: ISelect
    ) { 
        this.id = inputs.id
        this.title = inputs.title
        this.value = inputs.value
        this.selects = inputs.selects
    }

    setValue(value: string) { 
        this.value = value
    }
}

class InputText implements IText {
    public id: number
    public title: string
    public value: string
    public placeholder: string
    public type: IText['type'] = "inputText"

    constructor(
        inputs: IText
    ) { 
        this.id = inputs.id
        this.title = inputs.title
        this.value = inputs.value
        this.placeholder = inputs.placeholder
    }

    setValue(value: string) { 
        this.value = value
    }
}
let b: inputs[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "some select",
        value: "",
        selects: ["Moskow", "Bejing"],
        type: "inputSelect"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "some text input",
        value: "",
        placeholder: "yourName",
        type: "inputText"
    }
]
const classes = {
    inputText: InputText,
    inputSelect: InputSelect
}

let a = b.map(item => new classes[item.type](item)) \\here error
console.log(a)
```

full code typeScript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=80&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKpABwK5mQbwChkTlgATALmRGwFsAjaY0sYMAGwmoGcwpQAc0IBfQqEixEKVAGUIXBHggAPSCHI80GHHnzIWJMAE9M3ZACJQu+YrAWANIeQA3OB2zm+AkMNLIeBQglHl5+IQBtAF1RcXBoeCQ0ABVVZTUIDS10LFwifxMzaitcsFS1R2dMDmkACwB7DnJoMJ8-UjcPL3DfWMKUa1wtAF40W2C8AB8UtMJCBBqebNLxpTI6aog6TLBs1b0q7AYOYAQyKhp6JihD49PkNk5uttuTs87PVqFX+8C7UICPUE0R+Z361DkQSUEQA5P0YVFkKMSjYofY5v4EPUQN5sEp6lAABTOfyDXYQ-bOACUBAM-gKtWAPAAdBQkWRSiyKCTWIyWY8uOyyfz2FweUY+cyPihRsKpe5POKHpK-hMRhzdCzVSFnGJnIEwAA1BUQQnSr6+Gn6JVgSXS9nS3WxeaLZa6cp4YAbLjbcDZD0EUHnai0RjMfw4O5g0XPb4Ro5vVwmi3tEiRxPVOqNZpQFNB8EzNSw+GI5Fkj0WDGkLE4-h4sAE4n00jCiEe6m0m2Stmyzms8hdpnMgUyjVDYcxwcs+29zXyrpT5mZpANJrQIV95cQVc5p36iBGk1m5OAtpWunN5VDmdJhf+MRiLh4BjUYXRdkRZz5S8UagARicS8HhjYoeHqbYAjRSogPNSxoMvbVyWQCILAAWXqHgAGt6gAd0cSwACEIAAKyECwokAy8CxRXB9kre9KJIb9m1-ZAACZGPpEdQPAlBIDUMd7E4-xYIseDmy3HcWksYx6mwKAADk4G2cSuNMcwaLKNJ6NIMQYhrPhkAWOAlggdVmMEj0IVKD1OLJfZrNROxnSfZA4HZBhmToOBMEJdgtiRAA+GgIBwozXTMiJ-LoYd1KiPzIDoKkqXmbEwK4ZkOHqQRCTgKkgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the `b` is a union of inputs you need to narrow it again in the `map` function, unfortunately it's a limitation of typescript.

```js
let a = b.map(item =>
    item.type === 'inputSelect' ? new classes[item.type](item) : 
    item.type === 'inputText' ? new classes[item.type](item) : 
    undefined
);
```

or you can do a dynamic type check, then you need only 1 condition on any amount of interfaces in the `inputs` union.

```js
const checker = <T extends inputs>(item: T, cl: unknown): cl is ({new (a: T): InstanceType<(typeof classes)[T['type']]>}) => { 
    return classes[item.type] === cl;
};

let a = b.map(item => {
    const cl = classes[item.type];
    return checker(item, cl) ? new cl(item) : undefined;
}).filter((v): v is NonNullable<typeof v> => !!v);
```

Comment: I know this method
but this method confuses me, because if there are a lot of classes, you will have to write a ternary operator (or a conditional operator in general including a switch case) and the code will grow many times.
sorry for my English

Comment: I've added the second option, a bit more code, but then it supports any amount of interfaces in `inputs`.

Comment: Now I need to understand and tighten the Typescript