# How can I get proper types when using a list of constructors as input to a generic function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

#### Playground

I have created this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAZAkgISQbwLACgkikAXATxmQGEB7YKEgJwFd4SbGAeAFQD4kAvEmAQA7kgAUAOhkhGAcygAuJCGBkA2gF0AlIP7cCBYkggAPGBxJJ4dBkgBGzYABMANtBUZn7iJzVkvNqCSNpGhMTmlozW8G4gUFBI3q4ePKZmJBCuSbRgliLAJPx4ESZEtvRMrOyMEjDMDm4AlvA2NPl02SQq3HrYSAC+4eXEAPRjSDJSxsTD+LNEUVY28YlIeQXdOIvlE1Myu-O7yzFIAGbObM10qi4um11F6eZZORsdW0W8EradhT0kH0dmVyk5UtApA0oAALCQicQpXy-T5PEg6HRHEaRCwrS7Aa63eQQEiPAFQF6ZbIuXKogE-NgcFS0KosRlcPg6XrBUqjIiMEnMRjARw+DxQKTnZpuLJ1cG+fSiiFSP5fazNKpqRA0c42Wo6KRgEAwCTyjyKs0QFV07qY0HzY74OIJJIAQQybxpqEwUjJ2wGIBCAEYhgRnessK9qUl0BhfTaijhHMHQwsnXZYrUkkINK6ADTJLQEWNSED3P1FeFiPUcKAaAAMWgkGOLPrLDwTJCr4nZdaDTZbacq9lVaOzNcYEvO8RIAFljb9aoqS8TSZ2oIuOIOw3YaB4pG4aPIUf9ulA7UA) with the code used in this question.

#### Context

Let's say I am the author of a namespace called LIB. An excerpt of it looks like this:

```js
namespace LIB {
    type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

    export const bundles: Bundle<any>[] = []

    export class Bundle<T extends Component> {
        constructor(public component: T) { }

        // ...
    }

    export class Component {
        // ...
    }

    export function addComponent<T extends Component>(component: T) {
        bundles.push(new Bundle(component))
    }

    export function getComponents<T extends Component>(ctor: Constructor<T>): T[] {
        return bundles.filter(bundle => bundle.component instanceof ctor).map(bundle => bundle.component)
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how LIB could be used:

```js
class A extends LIB.Component { a = 1 }
class B extends LIB.Component { b = 1 }

const ctors = [A, B]
LIB.addComponent(new ctors[0]())
LIB.addComponent(new ctors[1]())

const components = ctors.flatMap(ctor => LIB.getComponents(ctor)) // <-- TS error here

console.log(components)
```

As shown in the playground, this runs fine and logs the expected `[A: {"a": 1}, B: {"b": 1}]`.

#### Questions

1. Why does TypeScript show the following error and how can I as the author of LIB prevent it? It is a requirement for `A` and `B` in the consuming code to have different properties.

```
Argument of type 'typeof A | typeof B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor<A>'.
  Type 'typeof B' is not assignable to type 'Constructor<A>'.
    Property 'a' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.(2345)
input.tsx(25, 33): 'a' is declared here.
```

2. TypeScript infers the type of `components` to `A[]`. I would have expected `(A|B)[]`, which is what the actual output at runtime shows. Why is this and how can I fix it?

### Similar questions

I have looked at some similar questions but did not manage to solve my problems above with the information found in them:

- [typeScript init dynamic class call by name (2345)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949964/typescript-init-dynamic-class-call-by-name-2345)
- [Build an array of classes to execute a static method with overloaded constructors in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754035/build-an-array-of-classes-to-execute-a-static-method-with-overloaded-constructor)
- [Abstract constructor type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886082/abstract-constructor-type-in-typescript)